# I am trying to connect to a database but it isn't working and I don't understand why

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am learing php and mysql, and I keep coming across this issue. Here is my code

```
    <?php

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];


   msql_connect("localhost","!userName!","!password!");

     msql_select_db("!dataBase!");


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="forum-style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" href="forum-script.js"></script>
    <title>Spread</title>
        </head>

<body>
    <form method="post">

        <input name="username" id="form-username1" placeholder="username">

        <input name="password" id="form-password1" placeholder="password">

        <input type="submit" value="Log in">



    </form>

    <p>Welcome to Spreads official testing platform. If you encounter any bugs, please click
    the "report bug" button.</p>



</body>
```

There is nothing in my java script file and my styling file. Here is my error message that gets displayed on my page index.php(the one that the code goes with :)

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function msql_connect() in /home3/notSureIfIShouldShowThis/public_html/spread/index.php on line 7`

my database is called !dataBase!, user is !userName!, password is !password!, and it is hosted with hostgator so local host :3 (I obviously changed it to those names on here only for safety)

Comment: Your are spelling "mysql" as "msql". Also "mysql_*" is removed in PHP 7 so you will continue to see this if you're not on the right PHP version. You should use "mysqli_" library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory... `Call to undefined function`.

Comment: @dan08 PDO is a good baseline. `mysqli` is full of sharp edges.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Answer (score 1):

mSql package needs to be compiled into your php version.
http://php.net/manual/en/msql.installation.php

Comment: This is certainly possible, but in all likelihood the OP is actually trying to connect to MySQL.

Answer (score -2):

You must use mysql_connect if you use PHP < 7.0 and mysqli_connect if your php version is greater than 7.0

Comment: WTF? Uhm... no. (ps I didnt downvote... this is just an obvious wtf answer)

Comment: Correction. You *can* use it with < 7.0, but you shouldn't.

Comment: Please stop using `mysql`. Use either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: yes yes it's better to use PDO, of course. but if he wants to discover Mysql and simply focus on queries without going through the object he can use simple method calls.
He wants to learn PHP, you're still not going to guide him already to MVC or frameworks. You have to go step by step.

Comment: `mysqli` has been in PHP since 5.0.

Comment: It's actually significantly easier to learn basic OOP and learn to execute queries with PDO than it is to learn to do them with ext/mysql only to have to learn another API later. PHP 5.6, which is the last version to even contain these functions, reaches its end of life in about 10 months.